# With Exoplayer2, how to always use default artwork (even if the audio has embedded artwork?)

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, albumart

My Android app has a large volume of remotely hosted media files (via AWS) and some contain embedded artwork.  When playing any of these audio media, I would like my default artwork - which is used when there is no embedded artwork - to be used instead.
I have tried

```
app:use_artwork="false"
app:default_artwork="@drawable/backgroundimage"
```

But contrary to what the Javadocs seem to suggest would be the result, I of course just get a black background.  (use_artwork="false" really seems to mean 'use no artwork' - while the Javadocs hint more that it means 'don't use embedded ID3 artwork')

Short of downloading gigabytes of media files and doing a batch operation on them all (a problem, because files are often added dynamically), is there a solution where I can suppress the embedded artwork and use my background?

Poking around a bit, I found https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic, but the problem here is that the files are being streamed via Exoplayer, not downloaded for me to manipulate programatically.

Answer (score 1):

After poking through the Exoplayer source a bit, here is what I came up with.  It is not absolutely ideal, because there is a quick flash of an embedded image before being replaced, but I think that is just a matter of moving the logic around to find the best place.

I removed the 
`app:use_artwork="false"`
from my activity_main.xml

In my BroadcastReceiver, upon the "trackChanged" event,
I added this (similar to what is done internally in the Exoplayer library itself):

```
Bitmap artWork = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.backgroundimage);
ImageView aw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.exo_artwork);
aw.setImageBitmap(artWork);
aw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Hey @drawk I wanted to know if how the playerview can be hidden when streaming audio with no artwork...I want to hide the black screen or have it wrap around the controls